# Is there anyone using TailwindUI package with React Native, can I inherit TailwindUI style that we're using on the website frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7, tailwind-ui

I have created a website using Ruby on Rails 7 with TailwindUI package: https://tailwindui.com/

Now, I'm planning to create a mobile app for this website, so I wonder can I reuse the TailwindUI style on the web for my react native app?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

[Nativewind](https://www.nativewind.dev/) is a good choice to use tailwind within react-native.

As for the TailwindUI components I haven't seen yet an implementation for native.